# My variabled in event listener is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I made an array of rgb colors and an click event listener to alert me when I click on the right color. The code looks like this excluding my array.

```
 var squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
 var pickedColor = colors[1];

 var colorDisplay = document.getElementById('colorDisplay');
 colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

 for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
     //add initial colors to squares
     squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

     // add click listeners to squares
     squares[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
         //grab color of clicked square
         var clickedColor = this.style.background;
         //compare color to pickedColor

         if (clickedColor == pickedColor) {
             alert('sdfsdfsd');
         } else {
             alert(clickedColor.text);
         }
     });
 }
```

On my if function only the else was passing and I would never get the first alert when the clickedColor == picked color, doing an alert on the clickedcolor.text shows it is undefined. I'm not sure how to fix this and unsure if its a browser issue, I'm using firefox version 57.

Comment: `this.style.background` is a string and has no `text` property

Comment: Just do `alert(clickedColor)`

Comment: `backgroundColor` translates to something like `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` what is the value of `pickedColor`?

Comment: picked color is the 1 spot in my array of colors, but in my event listener it just shows up as undefined. I tried using just alert(clickedColor), but then nothing appeared in my alert so I had to add .text.